# arbotix-m with dynamixel tutorial / example / doc?

Tags: ros, dynamixel-motor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

does anyone know an example / tutorial / doc that shows how to use arbotix-m with dynamixel?

i got the dynamixel_motor package working with dynamixel servos (via usb2dynamixel).

but i couldn't get any where with arbotix working with dynamixel via their arbotix-m board.  i couldn't find much documentation on ros wiki either.  it seems like the docs are really outdated too.

i can run "arbotix_terminal", see all the servos, and control all of them just fine via command line.  but i coulnd't control them in ros.  i'm not sure which nodes / topics / params should be used.

i'd like to compare usb2dynamixel vs. arbotix-m as far as how they work with dynamixel servos.

any point of reference is much appreciated.

d

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188104/arbotix-m-with-dynamixel-tutorial-/-example-/-doc?/) by [d](https://answers.ros.org/users/19443/d/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2014-07-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your question, but why you cannot use the rest of the [arbotix stack](http://wiki.ros.org/arbotix)? Afaik, it contains all you need to operate dynamixel motors (at least the AX-12 i have) and is updated to indigo. You just need to flash the arbotix_firmware and run the arbotix_driver to get full access to your servos with the ControllerGUI or MoveIt.

That said, I must mention that I us the arbotix stack with a different board (Robotis OpenCM9.04), but using an arbotix-m should be much easier.

**UPDATE**

arbotix_driver listen for joint positions on /command topics (std_msgs/Float64), and provides current joint positions on /joint_state topic, as explained [here](http://wiki.ros.org/arbotix_python?distro=indigo). But much easier is to run the arbotix_gui so you can move the servos with sliders.

If properly configured, arbotix_driver also provides you with controller interfaces, that high level tools like Moveit can use. For example, for a turtlebot arm, the joints (that is, servos) are:

```
joints: {
  arm_shoulder_pan_joint: {id: 1, neutral: 205, max_angle: 240, min_angle: -60, max_speed: 180},
  arm_shoulder_lift_joint: {id: 2, max_angle: 125, min_angle: -125, max_speed: 180},
  arm_elbow_flex_joint: {id: 3, max_angle: 150, min_angle: -150, max_speed: 180},
  arm_wrist_flex_joint: {id: 4, max_angle: 100, min_angle: -100, max_speed: 180},
  gripper_joint: {id: 5, max_speed: 90},
}
```

and the controllers

```
controllers: {
  arm_controller: {
    type: follow_controller,
    joints: [arm_shoulder_pan_joint, arm_shoulder_lift_joint, arm_elbow_flex_joint, arm_wrist_flex_joint],
    action_name: arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory,
    onboard: false
  }
}
```

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2014-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [d](https://answers.ros.org/users/19443/d/) on 2014-07-29**:
thansk jorge!  i got the firmware flashed on arbotix-m. through "arbotix_terminal" i can see all the servos and control all of them through the terminals.  my question is how to control these in ros. after running arbotix_driver, what nodes, topics, params, etc do you use to control the servos?

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2014-07-29**:
Answer updated. Hope I'm clearer now ^_^ !

**Comment by [d](https://answers.ros.org/users/19443/d/) on 2014-07-29**:
thanks again jorge.  i did run arbotix_driver (connected successfully).. then i ran "rostopic list" on command line, but i didn't see any "/command" as a topic?  what do you see when you do a "rostopic list" on your end? ps: i also don't see any of the services and params listed either.

**Comment by [d](https://answers.ros.org/users/19443/d/) on 2014-07-29**:
i can control these servos fine with dynamixel_motor package (via usb2dynamixel). i just don't understand how arbotix_ros package works (via arbotix-m board), especially how to send commands to a servo. i don't see these topics after running arbotix_driver; i do see the servos in arbotix_terminal

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2014-07-29**:
You need to configure arbotix_driver so he knows the servos you have, I put an example in the answer. Forget the controllers by now.

**Comment by [d](https://answers.ros.org/users/19443/d/) on 2014-07-29**:
yep, i sure did. here is my .yaml file, loaded in my launch file.

port: /dev/ttyUSB0
rate: 15
test: {
head_pan_joint: {id: 1, invert: true},
head_tilt_joint: {id: 2, max_angle: 100, min_angle: -100}
}

i published to /test/head_pan_joint/command std_msgs/Float64 but nothing happened...

**Comment by [d](https://answers.ros.org/users/19443/d/) on 2014-07-29**:
i got it working finally. i'm not sure exactly how/why i did it. i'm guessing that the problem was the baud rate. it was at 1000000 (i was using usb2dynamixel) while arbotix default rate is at 115200. after i set the servos baud rate to 115200, arbotix picked up and i now can control the servos.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2014-07-29**:
great! tell me if you need additional support. I have recently followed the way you are now on! I said nothing about connection parameters because I'm actually using a different board, and normally default parameters "should" work.

**Comment by [d](https://answers.ros.org/users/19443/d/) on 2014-07-31**:
hey @jorge, actually i have another question for you :)  what is the "controllers:{ }" above in your answer for?  how does it work?  i got the "joins: { }" working individually now, and hope to understand more about the controllers part.  thanks!

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2014-07-31**:
I'm not an expert on this, but afaik the follow_controller I use to operate my arm executes motion plans provided by moveit. That is, takes a secuence of configurations for and arm, and issue the appropriate individual commands to each servo. Interfaced by control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectory action